# Failed to fetch some archives ports.ubuntu.com

Tags: updates, 22.04, macbook-pro

I'm completely new at this and I'm trying to install ubuntu 22.04 using UTM on a M1 Mac and keep having the same issues. It cant locate package taskel and cant update saying "temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'". How do I resolve this?

How do I make sure the machine can see my network? Thank you

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not updating from a previous version but I tried running the commands (including from the DNS problem) and it doesn't seem to have resolved anything

Comment: That is a network error, not an internal error. Is your network up and available to this machine? Can the machine see the network? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1456004/edit) with clarifications to improve your question. Comments are intended to help improve your question. Comments are not intended for conversation.